# Prove that the inverse of an inverse is the function itself. $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have $f:X\to Y$, where $f$ is a bijection. How would we show that $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$

Comment: Why don't you show $f\circ f^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_Y$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X$?

Comment: I was wondering about that, that is what I did and it should suffice to prove this correct? I just was not sure that I was proving the same thing

Comment: Yes, it should work. A function $g$ is the inverse of $f^{-1}$ if it satisfies $g\circ f^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_Y$, etc. Since the inverse is unique, $g=f$, so $f=(f^{-1})^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you I completely understood it now. I was just missing that much I proved it and happy with the end result as well. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $(x,y)\in f$ then $(y,x)\in f^{-1}$ and vice versa.

Comment: Oh I see you want me to use the inverse of inverse relation! Thanks

Comment: @user43964: You can use what Yunone noted you above as well. I think that approach is faster.