# How sufficient is this proof for the inverse of an inverse being the identity relation?

Tags: solution-verification

I was studying mathematical analysis with the book *Introduction to Mathematical Analysis (Parzynski and Zipse, 1987)* and had a question regarding an exercise problem. It's actually the same one as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209110/prove-that-the-inverse-of-an-inverse-is-the-function-itself-f-1-1-f) but I was curious if my approach was also valid. The exercise is:

> Show that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is one-to-one then $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$.

The approach that I took is:

$$f: X \rightarrow Y\\f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X \\ (f^{-1})^{-1} : X \rightarrow Y \\ \therefore (f^{-1})^{-1} = f$$

It seems a bit...insufficient and inconvincing.

The approach laid out in the question I linked above is:

Since we know that if $f$ is one-to-one, $f \circ f^{-1} = i_X$ and $f^{-1} \circ f = i_X$.

If we say that we have some function $g$ where $g \circ f^{-1} = i_X$, then $g = f$ since inverses are unique. Since the inverse of $f^{-1}$ is $g$, we can conclude that $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$.

I was wondering if my approach also works, or if there should be a bit more rigor to it. Thanks.

Comment: It is false that $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ unless $f$ is onto. In general you can only say that $f^{-1}:f(X)\to X$.

Comment: Ah I just looked up the definitions for one-to-one and onto, and realized you're correct. I'm just curious, would my proof make sense if $f$ were a one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: No. The fact that two functions map $X\to Y$ doesn’t mean they are the same function. You must argue further and show somehow that they assume the same values everywhere.